# Symfony 3.3 Web Service Login form

Tags: php, rest, web-services, symfony, symfony-3.3

We are working in a login form, using simfony and a REST Webservice.
We have been searching in this link (http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html)

The goal is login in with the form and the REST web service, updating my session data, like, name, doc, email, etc.

And with this data allow or deny the access to some pages or functions.

When we submit the form, we don´t know how to use the data returned by the webservice, also if there are response or not.

This is our code:

SecurityController.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
class SecurityController extends Controller {
//    public function loginAction(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils) {
    public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils) {
//        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array('last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error));
//        return $this->render('AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig');
    }
    public function loginCheckAction() {
        $ca = $this->get('webservice_user_provider');
        print_r($ca);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Login.html.twig-----

```
   <form class="form-signin" action="{{ path('app_user_login_check') }}" method="POST">
```

Security.yml-----------------------

webservice:
        id: webservice_user_provider

Archivo services.yml----------------------------

```
  webservice_user_provider:
        class: AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider
```

WebserviceUserProvider.php-----------------------------

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Security/User/WebserviceUserProvider.php

namespace AppBundle\Security\User;

use AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Unirest;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

    protected $user;

    public function __contsruct(UserInterface $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username) {

        // make a call to your webservice here
        print_r("Estoy en el controlador de usuario");
        exit;
        $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
        $password = $this->request->get('password');
        $query = array('user' => $username, 'password' => _password);
        $userData = Unirest\Request::post('http://127.0.0.10:8888/login', $headers, $query);

// pretend it returns an array on success, false if there is no user

        if ($userData) {

            $datos = $userData->raw_body;

//            print_r($userData);
//            print_r($userData->body);
//            print_r($userData->raw_body);

            $username = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $password = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $salt = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $roles = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $doc = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $full_name = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $userLdap = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $userEpersonal = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $mail = $datos['ldap']['document'];
            $position = $datos['ldap']['document'];

            return new WebserviceUser($username, $password, $salt, $roles, $documento, $full_name, $userLdap, $userEpersonal, $mail, $position);
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
        sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
            sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class) {
        return WebserviceUser::class === $class;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a general overview, for implementation details you may want to ask another question.

A REST web service should be stateless, i.e. (to simplify a bit) should have no session. To implement ACL you may have different strategies.

The easiest one is to perform authentication on each request. You may use http authentication, or you can use an API key as many webservices do. Your webservice will always authenticate the user as the first step in each request.

A slightly more secure strategy is to have authentication return you a temporary token. I.e. first you request the login action with whatever authentication system you choose (you can even have more than one) and you get back a randomly generated token associated with your user. In the next requests you include this token and the system know who you are.